# Lazy loading based on scale or size

Tags: flutter

Let's say I have a program like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Dot Display',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: DotDisplay(),
    );
  }
}

class DotDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var num = 100;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: InteractiveViewer(
          boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(50),
          minScale: 1.0,
          maxScale: 20000.0,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                  for (var x = 1; x <= num; x++) for(var y=1; y <= num; y++) Dot(row: x, column: y, numStars: num)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Dot extends StatelessWidget {
  final int row;
  final int column;
  final int numStars;

  const Dot({required this.row, required this.column, required this.numStars});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var r = Random().nextInt(255);
    var g = Random().nextInt(255);
    var b = Random().nextInt(255);

    return Positioned(
      top: row * 5.0,
      left: column * 5.0,
      child: Container(
        width: (Random().nextInt(3)+1).floorToDouble(),
        height: (Random().nextInt(3)+1).floorToDouble(),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, r, g, b),
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That loads 10,000 dots of varying colors and sizes.  Is it possible to stop loading dots under a certain size as we zoom out?

I am imagining that it will require a `ListView` or `GridView` kind of solution, but I am not sure how to rig those to lazily load on size or scale.

Thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html and find "`Lazy Flutter Performance Session`"